# Properties of component are not accessible using windows refernce in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to change the ruler values on window focus.In this I ahve created the function which will work the window is focussed .I created the service-"WindowRef.ts" of window and gvae dependency to my component but the refernce I created for the window cannot acces the object proerties I defined in my component.ts file.
WindowRef.ts:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
function _window(): any {
  // return the native window obj
  return window;
}

@Injectable()
export class WindowRef {

  get nativeWindow(): any {
    return _window();
  }

}
```

appComponent:

```
export class AppComponent {
  //Creating the reference for the slider and reference for detect changes after destroying the slider

  @ViewChild('slider', { read: ElementRef }) sliderEl: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('slider') slider;

  timeInterval = [0, 15];
  window: any
  flag: boolean = true;
  step = 1;
  connectArray = [false, true, false];
  tooltips = [true, true];
  videoDuration: any = 50;
  Duration: any = 0;
  /**
   * Key values for the slider on creation and recreation 
   */
  keyConfig: any = {
    behaviour: 'drag',
    connect: this.connectArray,
    step: 1,
    tooltips: [true, true],                       // dynamic array for tooltip which will be updated in addInterval()
    margin: 0,
    range: {
      min: 0,
      max: this.videoDuration
    },
    pips: {
      mode: 'count',
      density: 3,
      values: 5,
      stepped: true
    }
  }
 // Constructor for intialising the time interval and running the js for the strating the after effects. 
      constructor(public cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef, public winRef: WindowRef) {
        //console.log('Window object', winRef.nativeWindow);
        this.window = winRef.nativeWindow;
        this.window.addEventListener('focus', this.focusFunction);
        try {
          initialiseJS();
        } catch (e) {
        }
      }

focusFunction() {                // Focus function is not working but console showing the focus out on debugging
    debugger;
    getVideoDuration(resp => {
      this.videoDuration = resp;
      console.log(this.keyConfig);
      this.keyConfig.range.max = this.videoDuration;
      this.slider.slider.destroy();
      this.flag = false;
      this.cdRef.detectChanges();
      this.flag = true;
    });
  }
```

'this' is not able to find the keyConfig properties and thus shows error "Cannot find the range of undefined". Can anyone please help me

Answer (score 0):

you need to put your windows definvation in `typings.d.ts`, then it will work as it working for me

```
/* SystemJS module definition */
declare var module: NodeModule;
interface NodeModule {
  id: string;
}
interface Window { my: any; }
```

and in component.ts do like this

```
     //below script helps to expose anglar function to javascript 
     window.my = window.my || {};
     window.my.namespace = window.my.namespace || {};
     window.my.namespace.publicFunc = this.OnTableButtonClick.bind(this);
```

OnTableButtonClick is angular function.

from html you can do like this

```
<input type='button' onclick='my.namespace.publicFunc(1);'
 value='Click me'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer would be

Write `this.window.addEventListener('focus', this.focusFunction.bind(this));`
in place of `this.window.addEventListener('focus', this.focusFunction);`

Comment: still the same error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined. Since 'this' is the window and It is not able to acces component properties

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 methods:

1 method:

Used the host property of the component to apply focus on all the elements of the component:

```
 @Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  host: {
    '(window:blur)': 'focusOutFunction($event)',
    '(window:focus)': 'focusInFunction($event)',
  }
})
```

and the getting the video duration from the callback when `focusOutFunction` is called and the setting that duartion when `focusInFunction` is called. This would acces the keyConfig object and all its propeties and the range prpoerty can also be accessed.

2 Method is:

using http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/ instead of using the host property we can simply send the parameter in function and in the inner function can use the `focusOutFunction`.See this:

```
this.window = winRef.nativeWindow;
    this.window.addEventListener('focus',((e)=>{
      return ()=>e.focusInFunction.call(e);
    })(this));
```

This would create the instance for the window to access the component properties and can be used perform operations.